# Failed to add reference to WikiNetParser. Please make sure that it is in the Global Assembly Cache

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, nuget, nuget-package

I am trying to add a reference to a project in Visual Studio 2012, by using 'Manage Nuget References'.  The package is 'Wiki .NET Parser' (version 2.5.2.0).

When I try to add it, I get the below:

```
Successfully installed 'WikiNetParser 2.5.2.0'.
Successfully uninstalled 'WikiNetParser 2.5.2.0'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Failed to add reference to 'WikiNetParser'. Please make sure that it is in the Global Assembly Cache.
```

I have also tried to create a clean, blank console project - But I still get the same problem.  Any ideas?

A search on Google returned nothing specific to this component

Comment: Could you try the version 2.5.2.1. I fixed it as Andrew suggested... let me know

Answer (score 1):

The package appears to have a malformed manifest. I've reported this issue to the author of the package.

Specifically: The Manifest contains this node:

```
  <frameworkAssemblies>
    <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="WikiNetParser" targetFramework=".NETFramework4.0" />
  </frameworkAssemblies>
```

Which tells NuGet to look for the "WikiNetParser" in the Core .Net 4.0 libraries, which of course does not exist. The node can simply be removed and the package should install successfully. If you want to try cracking the package open yourself, you can try using [NuGet Package Explorer](http://npe.codeplex.com).

Comment: @RadimKöhler I've removed my past comment saying that it is working - It installs successfully, yet no reference is added to the `Wiki.Net Parser` but only to `Antlr3.Runtime`.  Any ideas?

Comment: The Antlr3.Runtime should be part of the installation (in the lib folder). Please, try to reference this lib as well - only to be sure that it will be deployed in a bin. It is needed only for a runtime.

Comment: @RadimKöhler I've created a blank console application, and try to add a reference via Nuget.  The result is that only `Antlr3.Runtime` gets added.  Try this for yourself maybe?  I am using VS2012.  Could it be something with the manifest, as Andrew suggested?

Comment: I just tried. It is working for me ;( sorry for these problems, but at this moment I cannot repreoduce your issue ;(